# How to reload parent view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

How to update parent view, after i close the `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` view. If I use normal view I can reload my parent view. Issue only in `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`. Please help me. Thanks

```
 navigationController.modalPresentationStyle  = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
```

If I use

```
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle  = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
```

I can refresh the parent tableview.Issue only in UIModalPresentationFormSheet but I need to use UIModalPresentationFormSheet for popup view. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: why you want to reload the parent view?

Comment: I edit some data in "UIModalPresentationFormSheet" view. I want to show the changes in parent view.

Comment: you need some other to notify the change (KVO, NSNotificationCenter, delegate, pass a reference and call the method, so many way)

Comment: @Joshy Joseph .... exactly so many ways are there wat he(@xlc0212) told ....

Comment: I think the easiest method is to reload in 'viewWillAppear'. After you dismiss the form sheet your previous controller in the navigation controller will get 'viewWillAppear' called.

Comment: @George Unfortunately not. The form is above the view and the view remains visible. So `viewWillAppear` is not called.

Comment: Then..use delegation. I always use deletion for stuff like this but I thought 'viewWillAppear' would be easier. Just declare a protocol and a delegate property  , set it and call the method in the protocol at the appropriate time.

Comment: Ok I will try delegation

Comment: viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad are not called when a view is re-displayed. See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18493699/1532399

Answer (score 3):

IMO easiest way:

```
//FormController.h

@protocol FormDelegate;

@interface FormController : UIViewController 
...
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <FormDelegate> delegate;
...
@end

@protocol FormDelegate
-(void)didDismissForm;
@end

//MainViewController.h

#import "FormController.h"    
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FormDelegate>
...
```

Set the delegate when creating (or performing segue of) the FormController.
Call the delegate method when you dismiss it.
Implement the delegate method in the MainViewController.

```
-(void)didDismissForm {
   [self.tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

Comment: If I use

navigationController.modalPresentationStyle  = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
I can refresh the parent tableview.Issue only in UIModalPresentationFormSheet but I need to use UIModalPresentationFormSheet for popup view. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Works exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You should delegate the parentView of PresentModalView and should call referesh method on the viewWillDisappear of PresentModalView.

Otherwise, you can try to push notification and observe it in parentView.

```
    - (void) refreshMyParentViewController{
     NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
     [center postNotificationName:@"RefreshNeeded" object:self userInfo:refreshData];
}
```

//In ParentViewController -- AddObserver to detect data.
// And the method you want to call.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(delegateMethod:) 
                                                 name:@"RefreshNeeded" object:nil];

- (void)delegateMethod:(NSNotification *)notification {
      NSLog(@"%@", notification.userInfo);
      NSLog(@"%@", [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"RefreshObject"]);    
}



   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(delegateMethod:) 
                                                     name:@"RefreshNeeded" object:nil];

    - (void)delegateMethod:(NSNotification *)notification {
          NSLog(@"%@", notification.userInfo);
          NSLog(@"%@", [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"RefreshObject"]);    
    }
```